# Foundation Orbit loading spinner not disappearing

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

On the documentation, it says orbit will load a class of .orbit once it loads all of the necessary files. But on my website, it never stops the spinner and loads the element, but not the images. It doesn't seem to append .orbit to the class when the JavaScript executes.

Here's the HTML

```
        <li>
            <img src="./img/demos/demolarge1.png" />
            <div class="orbit-caption">The living room of the future</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="./img/demos/demolarge2.png" />
            <div class="orbit-caption">The new emporium by London</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="./img/demos/demolarge3.png" />
            <div class="orbit-caption">Warren Buffet's 8th stake in the real estate market</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
#featured { background: url(../img/spinner.gif) center center #f4f4f4 no-repeat; height: 450px; }
#featured img { display: none; }
#featured.orbit-container { background: none; }
#featured.orbit-container img { display: block; }
```

What am I missing here? The website is at biggdesigns.com
Thank you!

Solution: I figured out I was using the version 3 documentation with version 4 installed. Gah!

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate div for your loading gif with a class of `.loading` and set the gif as the background for this. Then give your images a class of something like `.featuredIMG`.

In your CSS do the following:

```
.featuredIMG{display: none;}
```

Then in your JQuery, bind the slider initialisation and hide/show for the respective classes to the `$(window).load` event:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#featured").orbit();
  $(".featuredIMG").show();
  $(".loading").hide();

});
```

This will display the loading gif until all the images have loaded, then hide the loading div, initialise the slider and show the slider content. This is the cleanest way I have found for doing it.

EDIT: place the loading div outside of the `#featured` div and set its height and width to that of the slides.